# Delete using rawQuery using order by and limit Android

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to delete data from SQLLite DB using rawQuery. It works without order by and limit parameters using where clause, But I'm trying to delete using these parameters and it throw exception. I have tried using execSQL

```
public void deleteInvertersLimitedData() {




    database.execSQL("DELETE FROM abc order by created_date limit 10; ");

}
```

Also this one not working

```
public void deleteInvertersLimitedData() {

    database.rawQuery("DELETE FROM abc ORDER BY created_by limit 1", null);
}
```

[Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upeg5.png)

Comment: quick googling would point similar question asked here already ... the main better question would be if android's sqlite is builded with  SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT flag

Comment: Exception image is attached.

Comment: @MuhammadRashidAbbas please do not paste images of stack traces, copy and paste the stack trace and then format it as code.

Comment: @MuhammadRashidAbbas have you tried my answer ?

Comment: @JohnJoe I'm used your query it works I think. Try to run it with data inside table. otherwise query is running perfect. Good logic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this

```
db.execSQL("DELETE from abc where user_id IN (SELECT user_id from abc where id = '1' limit 10)");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Stack Overflow is not allowing me to upvote your answer But I can support your answer in comment. Thanks Again.

Comment: What is not complete here?

Comment: I edited my comment above.

Comment: You can support my answer by mark it as correct [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/377443)

Comment: My reputation is less then 15. thats why not allowing me to do it .